# php regex for double underscore

Tags: php, regex

I have a php regex expression to check email address:

[image]

Here is a string: header__change_seq, which is supposed to return zero matches but instead, it returns positive result. I know that the problem is caused by the double underscore '__' right after 'header'.

How can I let the regex to detect the mixed occurrence of single and double underscore in this kind of string?

```
^(?!(.*(MATCH|MATCH)))(.*[_\- ])?(EMAIL|EMAILS)?[123]?[_\- ]?(ADDRESS|ADDR)?[123]?([_\- ].*)?$
```

Comment: Why is the regex an image, not a text? Why.. just .. why?

Comment: because the backslash distorted the string

Comment: Paste it as is, we'll fix. Also, please add the pattern requirements, what kind of strings it is supposed to match and why.

Comment: Funny looking email addresses.

Comment: ^(?!(.*(MATCH|MATCH)))(.*[_\- ])?(EMAIL|EMAILS)?[123]?[_\- ]?(ADDRESS|ADDR)?[123]?([_\- ].*)?$

Comment: it should return 0 if the string looks like this: header__change_seq

Comment: someone in our company made a mistake by using __ instead of _ for the naming of variables in our database. My regex is supposed to catch the key words to determine the data domain. I didn't expect the occurrence of __ together with _ in one string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use limit repeat `{1,2}`. This mean minimum occurrences  of `_` is 1 and maximum is 2.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Would you please insert your patch into the regex: ^(?!(.*(MATCH|MATCH)))(.*[_\- ])?(EMAIL|EMAILS)?[123]?[_\- ]?(ADDRESS|ADDR)?[123]?([_\- ].*)?$

Comment: `^(?!(.*(MATCH|MATCH)))(.*[_{1,2}\- ])?(EMAIL|EMAILS)?[123]?[_{1,2}\- ]?(ADDRESS|ADDR)?[123]?([_{1,2}\- ].*)?$`                                               Try This . and can write me some test case if not work with you

Comment: header_ in group 3: (.*[_{1,2}\- ]); _change_seq in group 6: ([_{1,2}\- ].*)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the fix doesn't work. I want it treats __ the same as dash '-' and space ' '